# Writing from GSheet (using AppScript) to Database

Tags: database, google-apps-script

From GSheet, I am trying to pass values from a column range (K11:K23) into a table in database. So far I am able to establish a connection but this statement,

```
Logger.log(values)
```

is only printing the first row for me. I am iterating through the entire range so not sure where I am going wrong here. Please help!

```
function writeToDatabase() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1fFnY');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XYQ'); 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange('K11:K23'); 
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  

  try {
    // MySQL database credentials
    var server = "ar.mysql.database.azure.com";
    var port = 0000;
    var db = "a";
    var user = "a@analytics-master.mysql.database.azure.com";
    var pwd = "xyz";

    // Creating a connection to the MySQL database
    var url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port +"/" + db;
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
    
    // Logger.log(conn)
    // Looping through the values and write to the database
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var row = values[i];
      
      Logger.log(values)
      
      var valueAsString = row[0].toString();
      
      // inserting data into your table
      var sql = 'INSERT INTO R_s (u_e) VALUES (?)';

      // Preparing the SQL statement
      var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      stmt.setString(1, valueAsString);

      Logger.log(valueAsString)

      // Executing the SQL query
      stmt.executeUpdate();
      stmt.close();
    }

    // Closing the database connection when done
    conn.close();
    
    Logger.log('Data inserted into the database');
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log('Error:', err);
  }
}
```

Comment: The range "K11:K23" returns an array of 13 rows and 1 column.  So in your for loop try `Logger.log("value = "+values[i][0]);`.

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details. You should include some sample data showing the data to be read from the spreadsheet , the logs expected, and the logs that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your sql because this works for me:

```
function writeToDatabase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  var rg = sh.getRange('K11:K23');
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var row = vs[i];
    let v = row[0].toString();
    Logger.log(`This is my data ${v}`);
  }
}
```

I can't reproduce the database stuff so I can't help you any further